# DotNetNuke reports Skin Error due to not well formed server tag

Tags: dotnetnuke, skinning

this may seem trivial but i can't figure out why DNN reports this error, my markup seems clean..

skin worked fully functional until i added a background via css and concluding parsed the skin..

checked for unclosed brackets or missing placeholders but can't find any.

any ideas?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>ITM America</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skin.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ruda&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="headerContainer">
            <div id="logoPane" runat="server">
                <object id="dnnLOGIN" codetype="dotnetnuke/server" codebase="LOGIN">
                    <param name="CssClass" value="user" />
                </object>
            </div>
            <div id="contactPaneEmail" class="contact" runat="server">
                hello@asdasd.com
            </div>
            <div id="contactPaneTelNumber" class="contact"runat="server">
                TELEPHONE +1 1234567899
            </div>
            <div id="navPane" runat="server">
                topnav
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bodyContainer">
            <div id="generalSloganPane" runat="server">
                ORGANIZE FLEXIBILITY
            </div>
            <div id="tabPane" runat="server">
                METHODS
            </div>
            <div id="specificSloganPane" runat="server">
                specificSlogan
            </div>
            <div id="ContentPane" runat="server">
                basdasd
            </div>
            <div id="imagePane" runat="server">
                image123
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" runat="server">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a missing space before a runat=server tag, maybe this solves:

```
<div id="contactPaneTelNumber" class="contact"runat="server">
            TELEPHONE +1 1234567899
        </div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! This kind of errors are often hard to find, isn't it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious problems, but DotNetNuke will generate an .ascx file for the .html file you uploaded. You should look in (and/or paste) that file. Often times you'll see that error when there are improperly nested quote marks.